# How to select combination of data from different tables(Table1,Table2,Table3,Table4,Table5) into achieve the output mentioned below in oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle

First of all, thank you for your time helping me!

I have the following (example) 5 tables.

Table 1

| username |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 2 |
| 3 |
| 4 |
| 5 |

Table 2

| Username | Role |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | D |
| 2 | O |
| 3 | S |
| 4 | A |

Table 3

| Name | Privilege | Option |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | AD | N |
| 2 | CC | Y |
| 3 | DT | N |
| 4 | MS | Y |

Table 4

| Username | Option1 | option2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | T | T |
| 2 | F | T |
| 3 | T | F |

Table 5

| Username | privilege_1 | AO |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | E | No |
| 2 | I | Yes |
| 3 | U | Yes |
| 4 | A | No |

I'm trying to achieve Output that should be like  :

1. All the users from five tables in one 'username' column
2. and their corresponding role(from table2),privilege(from table3),option1(from table4),option2(from table4),privilege_1(from table5) into 'Type' column
3. and if role(from table2) for a user is in (D , O , S) then HP should be 'Yes' for those users, if privilege (from table3 ) is in 'CC', 'MS' for that user then HP is 'Yes', option1,option2(from table4) is 'T' for that user then HP is 'Yes', (Privilege_1 (from table5) is 'U' and AO(from table5) is 'Yes' for that user then HP is 'Yes'

| username | type | HP |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | D | Yes |
| 2 | O | Yes |
| 3 | S | Yes |
| 4 | A | No |
| 1 | AD | No |
| 2 | CC | Yes |
| 3 | DT | No |
| 4 | MS | Yes |
| 1 | T | Yes |
| 2 | F | No |
| 3 | T | Yes |
| 1 | T | Yes |
| 2 | T | Yes |
| 3 | F | No |
| 1 | E | No |
| 2 | I | No |
| 3 | U | Yes |
| 4 | A | No |
| 5 | (null) | (null) |

The query that I have written is :

```
select
  username,
  case
    when table2.role is not null then table2.role
    when table3.privilege is not null then table3.privilege
    when table4.option1 is not null then table4.option1
    when table4.option2 is not null then table4.option2
    when table5.privilege_1 is not null then table5.privilege_1
  end as type
  case
    when table2.role in ('D','S') then 'Yes'
    when table3.privilege in ('CC', 'MS') then 'Yes'
    when table4.option1 = 'T' then 'Yes'
    when table4.option2 = 'T' then 'Yes'
    when table5.privilege_1 in ('U') and table4.AO = 'Yes' then 'Yes'
    else 'No'
  End as HP
from table1
  left join table2
    on table1.username = table2.username
  left join table3
    on table1.username =table3.name
  left join table4
    on table1.username = table4.username
  left join table5
    on table1.username = table5.username;
```

I have worked on above query but I was not able to get the entire data.

Comment: You should use `` to format your data/SQL, it's easier to read :)

Comment: So the question is: "Please, ask me a question for which I should answer with this result"? Please, clarify your requirement, describe, what is wrong with your current attempt and what is the problem with its resolution (you do not know why the result is that or you do not know how to express something in SQL).

Comment: Astentx,I was looking  for how can I achieve  the output mentioned above by combination of data from five tables (table1,table2,table3,table4,table5). I have some query written (sql query mentioned above but Yes, No in HP is missing for table4 data in output and I couldn't see data for table 5 in output 'type' column but I can see 'Yes' or 'No' for same in HP of the output. So could you help me in achieving the correct output (output that I was looking for mentioned above) from combination of 5 tables((table1,table2,table3,table4,table5)).

Comment: Please, [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/68712442/edit) your original question and provide all the required details within it. It is not clear what is the question you want to answer with some SQL code. No any rules for data transformation, so the question lacks required details.

Comment: Astentx, I have updated necessary information to the question. please check and let me know if it's still lacks required information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you join multiple tables like that on `username`, try starting out with `select * from ...`. Notice that all of the table values are in the same row! You can't split them back out into separate rows by using CASE, you need to start out with all of them in separate rows. I think you want to UNION those secondary table rows together.

Example:

```
select *
from table1
left join (select username, table2.role as type, 
        case when table2.role in ('D','O','S') then 'Yes' else 'No' as HP 
        from table2
      union 
      select name as username, privilege as type, 
        case when table3.privilege in ('CC', 'MS') then 'Yes' else 'No' as HP 
        from table3
      union
      select username, option1 as type, 
        case when table4.option1 = 'T' then 'Yes' else 'No' as HP 
        from table4
      union
      select username, option2 as type, 
        case when table4.option2 = 'T' then 'Yes' else 'No' as HP 
        from table4
      union
      select username, privilege_1 as type, 
        case when table5.privilege_1 in ('U') and table5.AO = 'Yes' then 'Yes' else 'No' as HP 
        from table5) x
on x.username = table1.username;
```

Comment: Thanks for the query. With this I was  able to get respective information in "type" for all the users. But I'm not getting Yes, No mapped correctly with respective "type"